# Why is a double-void pointer required here? Dynamic "generic" array

Tags: c, pointers, declaration, calloc, pointer-to-pointer

I tried to implement a form of collections-library. I do it all the time, when learning a new language, because it teaches most of the language details.

So, I started with a form of "generic" dynamic array. Well it is not really generic, because it just holds pointers to the actual data.
But to be honest, I don't fully understand, why I need a double void pointer here.

The Vector struct defined in my header file (I declared every method and #include in the header file, but I omitted this here to keep the code readable. I also ommitted some bounds checks)

```
typedef struct {
    size_t capacity; //the allocated capacity
    size_t length; //the actual length
    void **data; //here I don't fully understand, why I need a double pointer.
} Vector;
```

Here is my implementation of a few methods, where the compiler complains when I use a single void pointer in my struct, so `void *data` instead of `void **data`.

```
#include "utils.h"

const size_t INITIAL_SIZE = 16;

//Creates a new empty vector.
Vector *vec_new(void) {
    printf("sizeof Vector is: %ld", sizeof(Vector));
    Vector *vec = malloc(sizeof(Vector));
    vec->length = 0;
    vec->capacity = INITIAL_SIZE;
    void *data = calloc(INITIAL_SIZE, sizeof(void*));
    if(data == NULL) {
        free(vec->data);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    vec->data = data;
    return vec;
}

//This method appends the specified value at the end of the vector.
void vec_push(Vector *vec, void *data) {
    if(vec->length == vec->capacity-1) {
        vec_resize(vec);
    }
    vec->data[vec->length] = data;
    vec->length += 1;
}

//gets the value at the specified index or NULL if index is out of bounds.
void *vec_get(Vector *vec, size_t index) {
    return vec->data[index];
}

//Resizes the vector to 1.5x its current capacity.
void vec_resize(Vector *vec) {
    vec->capacity *= 1.5;
    void *data = realloc(vec->data, sizeof(void*) * vec->capacity);
    if(data == NULL) {
        free(vec->data);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    vec->data = data;
}
```

It seems like here is where the magic happens, which i do not yet understand:

```
void *data = malloc(...);
vec->data = data;
```

Malloc/calloc return a void pointer, so i either have to declare an actual type or just using the returned void pointer. So the first line is clear.
`vec->data` is, under the assumption I do not use a double pointer in the struct definition equivalent to `(*vec).data` as far as I understand it. So basically this line should assing a void pointer to a void pointer.

Can maybe someone explain it to me in simple terms, why exactly a single void pointer is not enough here or where I might misunderstand something.

Comment: At a glance, `void**` seems plain wrong. `vec->data = data;` is also plain wrong and you won't get a compiler error/warning for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But to be honest, I don't fully understand, why I need a double void pointer here.

**Some background first - maybe you already know that:**

A pointer of the type `someType *` is a pointer to some variable of the type `someType` **or** to an array of variables of the type `someType`.

A pointer of the type `someType **` is a pointer to a variable of the type `someType *` - this means: A pointer to a pointer to a variable of the type `someType`.

A pointer of the type `void *` is a pointer to anything; because the compiler does not know to what kind of element this pointer points to, it is not possible to access such an element directly.

In contrast to this, it is known what variable a pointer of the type `void **` points to: It points to a variable of the type `void *`.

**Why you need `void**` in this position:**

The key are the lines:

```
vec->data[vec->length] = data;
...
return vec->data[index];
```

In these lines, the code accesses the data `vec->data` points to. For this reason, `vec->data` cannot be `void *` but it must be `xxx *` while `xxx` is the type of data the pointer `vec->data` points to. And because `vec->data` points to a pointer of the type `void *`, `xxx` is `void *` so `xxx *` is `void **`.

> ```
> vec->data = data;
> ```

Your observation is correct: `vec->data` is of the type `void **` and `data` is of the type `void *`.

The reason is that `malloc()` returns some memory and the compiler does not know which kind of data is stored in this memory. So the value returned by `malloc()` is `void *` and not `void **`.

In the automotive industry, you would use an explicit pointer cast like this:

```
vec->data = (void **)data;
```

The expression `(xxx *)y` tells the compiler that the pointer `y` points to some data of the type `xxx`. So `(void **)` tells the compiler that the pointer points to an element of the type `void *`.

However, in desktop applications you often don't write the `(void **)`.

Comment: "In the automotive industry, you would use an explicit pointer cast like this" No this is wrong, the use of void pointer conversions is not allowed in automotive systems to begin with. Mainly because type-generic programming doesn't make any sense in deterministic real-time systems. See MISRA-C:2012 rules 11.5 and 11.6.

Comment: @Lundin That's right: `void *` pointers are typically avoided completely. However, I was working on low-layer software (e.g. device drivers) where it is required to "justify" some MISRA or "QA/C" warnings because accessing the DMA (as an example) cannot be done in a 100% MISRA-compliant way. In such situations, suppressing a warning (with a justification in a comment) about an explicit cast from `void *` to some other pointer was allowed in the company where I worked while implicit casts were never allowed.

Comment: Often you can use a `uint8_t*` as a generic pointer when dealing with raw data.

Comment: thank you for your useful comments.
I'm comming from high level languages, mostly Java, so I thought it would be a good Idea to implement some form of a generic, dynamic array. Your comments made me think wheter this may not be the best idea in C. Especially because i got a job in the automotive industry here in Germany, thats the reason I work on my C skills, so im deeply interested in a good solution. Maybe I have to post the whole code on codereview.stackexchange to get a overall feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pointer of the type

```
T *p1;
```

where T is some type specifier as for example void then pointer to this pointer will be declared like

```
T **p2 = &p1.
```

In this call of calloc

```
calloc(INITIAL_SIZE, sizeof(void*))
```

you are going to allocate an array of pointers of the type `void *`. The function returns a pointer to the first element of the allocated array. So you need to write

```
void **data = calloc(INITIAL_SIZE, sizeof(void*));
```

To make it more clear let's assume that you need to allocate dynamically an integer array. In this case you will write

```
int *data = calloc( INITIAL_SIZE, sizeof( int ) );
```

So dereferencing the pointer `data` like `*data` you will get an object of the type `int` more precisely the first element of the allocated array.

When elements of the array have the type `void *` then dereferencing the pointer `data` like `*data` you must to get a pointer of the type `void *` (the first element of the allocated array). So to make the operation correct the pointer `data` shall have the type `void **`.

Comment: thank you, you definitely cleared things up. Thanks!